# I can't figure why I'm getting unboundLocalError

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.8 and python 2.7 but I keep on getting unbounLocalError. It looks all is ok with the code in my views.py. But it keep on local variable 'cd' referenced before assignment. I will be glad if someone could provide the solution

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()

    if 'query' in request.GET:

        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results =     SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
        # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                 'cd': cd,
                                                 'results': results,
                                                 'total_results':  total_results})
```

search.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if "query" in request.GET %}
        <h1>Posts containing "{{ cd.query }}"</h1>
        <h3>Found {{ total_results }} result{{     total_results|pluralize }}</h3>
        {% for result in results %}
            {% with post=result.object %}
            <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">    {{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
            {% endwith %}
        {% empty %}
            <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <p><a href="{% url "blog:post_search" %}">Search again</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Search for posts</h1>
        <form action="." method="get">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to return a context dictionary containing `cd`, `results`, and `total_results` even if your `if` clauses are not satisified. You should fix your indentation:

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()

    if 'query' in request.GET:

        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results =     SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
        # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
            # Indent this line:
            return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                 'cd': cd,
                                                 'results': results,
                                                 'total_results':  total_results})
```

Comment: I have fixed the indentation as u did but the same error is shown. That's why the whole stuff seems confusing. Have a look at my search. html file

Comment: Update your question to post the whole error stack trace and make sure that you are using the same indentation character (either all spaces or all tabs) in your Python code.

Comment: I am using all tabs for my indentation but the error is still there

Comment: Please post the stack trace.